# Vscode API - Help Identifying View Context

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

So I know how to get a menu item on my tree view using `view/item/context` in the `package.json`, this gives the menu for each "item"

[image: Item Context]

This is working well and all but I need to have a menu accessible even when my tree view contains no items.
See image below:

[image: Unknown Context]

Is there a way to do this? I read about the possibilities [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/tree-view) but was unable to find the right one.

Comment: Hm... I'd say chances are that's not possible in custom views.

Comment: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
~